# How to show only the date, the title and a litle "summary" of my WordPress post in my custom theme?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I have the following doubt about how show posts into a page.

I have this page belonging to an old custom legacy blog that I am build again using WordPress: http://www.asper-eritrea.com/comunicati.asp

As you can see in this page are presented some posts using the following structure: **date** followed by the **post title** followed by a **short summary**

What I want to do in WordPress is something like it.

So I have create this page that show the posts lists: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/category/legacyposts/

As you can see in this page are shown the posts (the formattation is horrible because I imported the post from the old website but I will work on it in a second time).

The main problem is that if the post is very long it is shows all of its contents.

This is the code of this page (**category.php**) is:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Contenuti (griglia) -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Lead presentazione -->
    <section id="presentazione">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!--<h1 class="text-center"><small>Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</small></h1>-->
                <h1 class="text-center title">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1>
                <h1 class="text-center leadTitle">Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People</h1>
                <!--
                <p class="lead text-center">
                    Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People
                </p>
                -->
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /section presentazione -->
    <!-- Progetti in evidenza -->

    <header class="header-sezione">
        <h2>Ultimi Articoli</h2>
    </header>

    <?
    // get the term using the slug and the tag taxonomy
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'featured', 'post_tag' );
    // pass the term_id to tag__not_in
    query_posts( array( 'tag__not_in' => array ( $term->term_id )));
    ?>

    <?php
        if (have_posts()) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

            endwhile;
        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part('content', 'none');

        endif;
        ?>

    </section>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So what I want to do is that, for each post, the loop show only the date, the title and the beginning of my post (for example a specific number of character).

What can I do to obtain this result?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should start reading the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page),  that way you can know how wordpress works.

Now, the category.php template is trying to find other template part with this code:

```
get_template_part("content", get_post_format());
```

This code is looking for content-post format.php, in case that file doesn't exist, wordpress automatically looks for content.php and that file is the one you have to work.

You must find this file and you use the following functions

```
the_excerpt();

get_the_date();

the_title()
```

Now if you want to control the size of the excerpt, you can use this function inside of function.php.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```